# How to inflate GraphQL items before resolving fields?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAJWHHUz8_8) tutorial for GraphQL in node. I have finished the tutorial but am now extending on my own.

Its a GraphQL API on top of the XML-based goodreads API. I have trouble dealing with the authors have books have authors have books etc problem.

Consider the following two GraphQLObjects:

```
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    description: '...',

    fields: () => ({
        title: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: xml =>
                xml.title[0]
        },
        isbn: {
           type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: xml =>
                xml.isbn[0]
        },
        authors: {
            type: GraphQLList(AuthorType2),
            resolve: xml =>
                xml.authors[0].author
        }
    })
});

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Author',
    description: '...',

    fields: () => ({
        name: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: xml =>
                xml.name[0]
        },

        books: {
            type: GraphQLList(BookType),
            // if author not inflated, this fails
            resolve: xml => xml.books[0].book
        }

        //here could be another item that fails on uninflated authors
    })
});
```

The root API is on /author and gives a fully expanded author, along with books which in turn have a snippet of author-data (lets assume it only has the id and name).

My question is how to expand this reduced author to it's full state, to include books and resolve those. I cannot do this when resolving authors field in book because the user might only need the author's name, thus data is loaded that isn't needed.

I also cannot do it when resolving books, since then if another field that also needs the inflated state is added, no way of saving state is available so the inflation has to happen twice per author.

Can anyone explain? Is there some way to alter the state of AuthorType during the resolving of it's fields? Some other workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to see which fields are actually queried. The resolve function's fourth argument is a lesser used bit, dubbed `info`. In it, you can explore the fieldNode tree queried for the specific field.

You can use that information in the `authors` field resolve function to decide if you're going to load the extra data. something like:

```
authors: {
    type: GraphQLList(AuthorType),
    resolve: (xml, args, context, info) => {
        if (!info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections....) // It's a pretty robust structure 
            return xml.authors[0].author;

        return loadAuthors(xml.title[0]) // However you load authors...
    }
}
```

As for the Type of the field. You can look into [GraphQL interface and union types](https://medium.com/the-graphqlhub/graphql-tour-interfaces-and-unions-7dd5be35de0d).

Comment: Sure then you know what to request. But the problem remains: if we have two fields in the book type that require the book api to be called, i still need a way to fetch once, and retrieve later (for the 2nd field). This info doesn't actually provide a method for this. Some kind of state field would be best i think

Comment: Sorry I just figured out that this is when resolving the list, so this makes sense, thanks

Comment: I have found a better solution and posted below, but yours is technically correct. So I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

So I have been looking around and it turns out this isn't the right approach for such a problem. It is best to use some kind of per-request chaching like [dataloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dataloader) and have every field that needs the additional endpoint call the dataloader. This way if none of the fields requiring the details request are queried, no 2nd call is done. Also, because of the caching, if there are multiple fields queried that require the detail call, it's only called once and cached.

```
    books: {
        type: GraphQLList(BookType),
        // if author not inflated, this fails
        resolve: (obj, args, context) => {
            return context.booksLoader.load(obj.id)
                   .then(obj => obj.books)
        }
    }

    someOther: {
        type: GraphQLList(BookType),
        // if author not inflated, this fails
        resolve: (obj, args, context) => {
            return context.booksLoader.load(obj.id)
                   .then(obj => obj.someOther)
        }
    }
```